# app component in console application on yii2

Tags: php, yii2, components, console-application

file commands/FlagController.php
    namespace app\commands;

```
use yii;
use yii\console\Controller;
use yii\base\Component;
use app\components\flag\AbstractFlagService;
use app\components\flag\FlagService;

class FlagController extends Controller
{
   public function actionCheck()
   {
        $flagService = \Yii::$app->get('flag-service');
        if(Yii::$app->flag->run()) {
        echo true;
        }
   }
}
```

config\console.php

```
 <?php use \yii\console\controllers\MigrateController;

 $config = [
   'id' => 'basic-console',
    'controllerNamespace' => 'app\commands',
    'components' => [
    'flag' => [
        'class' => 'app/components/flag/FlagService',
        ]
     ],
 ];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {

$config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
$config['modules']['gii'] = [
'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
  ];
 }
```

I have a error Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class app/components/flag/FlagService does not exist'. How to use app-component in console application on yii2

Comment: `app/components/flag/FlagService` should be `app\components\flag\FlagService` i guess.

Comment: Exactly, I'd suggest you'd do as @InsaneSkull is suggesting